# Create wine-comaptible desktop files with optional file argument

Tags: wine, .desktop

I'm using MS Office 2007 via Wine/PoL and I've made the desktop files for them like that:

For starting:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Word 2007
GenericName=Game
Comment=PlayOnLinux
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Microsoft Word 2007"
Icon=/home/sebastian/.PlayOnLinux//icones/full_size/Word 2007
Categories=Office;
```

For file opening: (`z:` is the wine link to `/`)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Mit Word 2007 öffnen
GenericName=Game
Comment=PlayOnLinux
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Microsoft Word 2007" z:%f
Icon=/home/sebastian/.PlayOnLinux//icones/full_size/Word 2007
Categories=Office;
```

However, the file opening shortcut doesn't accept files with spaces (they get replaced by `%20`).

Now I want to merge those two files into one, which should start Word and, if supplied, opens a document, which may contain spaces.

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for myself. I created the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$2" != "" ]
 then
  mode="open"
  DATA="file:///Z:$2"
  DATA=${DATA// /%20}
else
  mode="noopen"
fi
case $1 in
  winword)
    if [ $mode == "open" ]
    then
      /usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Microsoft Word 2007" "$DATA"
    else
      /usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Microsoft Word 2007"
    fi
  ;;
  excel)
    if [ $mode == "open" ]
    then
      /usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Microsoft Excel 2007" "$DATA"
    else
      /usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Microsoft Excel 2007"
    fi
  ;;
  pwrpoint)
    if [ $mode == "open" ]
    then
      /usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Microsoft Powerpoint 2007" "$DATA"
    else
      /usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Microsoft Powerpoint 2007"
    fi
  ;;
  *)
    exit
  ;;
esac
```

It converts the file name to a URL (`file:///Z:/home/sebastian/Documents/test.docx`). It also determines whether to supply a second argument or not, so Office won't say `File "Z:" not found`.

The launchers look like this now: (This one for word)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Word 2007
GenericName=Word Processor
Comment=PlayOnLinux
Type=Application
Exec=/home/sebastian/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2007/MSOfficeExecutor.sh winword %f
Icon=/home/sebastian/.PlayOnLinux//icones/full_size/Word 2007
Categories=Office;
```